# What does this piece of code actaully do?

Tags: python, format

I am a bit of a newcomer and am pouring through some tutorials like water from a firehose when I encountered an acquaintance post something on social media that looks like this:

```
print(
    [format(x, "c") for x in range(32,127)]
)
```

Now, I went and ran the code and was perplexed to see it print out a large set of varying characters. I tried to skip ahead to some tutorials talking about format and also perused the site: https://pyformat.info/ to no avail.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: `format(x, "c")` does the same as `chr(x)`.

Comment: You might want to type "ASCII" to your favorite search engine.

Comment: I think the reason people are voting you down is that your question title is ambiguous. It's a question about python and `format`, which you tagged, but the title itself is a mystery (and folks are feeling crotchety, I guess). Be a little more descriptive in the title, and you should be golden!

Comment: I'm wondering if it's the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that's actually the point of confusion, or at least a contributor.

Comment: Hey Erekalper, I'm not fussed. While I agree that the title may be ambiguous, I think we have all been at the point where a concept was so new that we don't even know how to phrase a question properly. Oh well, I tried to point out that I looked into this problem myself. Alas! The community remains as astute as I remember it.

Answer (score 2):

To be fair, running help(format) in the Python terminal doesn't give a lot of insight into what format() does. The official documentation page, specifically Section 7.1.3.1. of the following link goes into a lot more detail: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

format(x, 'c') converts the integer (x for x in range(32,127)) to the corresponding unicode character before printing.

Answer (score 2):

[This should help you understand format](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/format)

Basically, your code prints every character with an Unicode value between 32 and 127.

Comment: This was the type of documentation I sorely needed! Thank you, sir! And apologies to all whos time I may have squandered.

Comment: Except that "c" formats the value as the "Corresponding [_Unicode_](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character". You have to be cautious when talking about ASCII; it is rare or highly specialized and many people might not know of it—besides being irrelevant to the question.